# What happens in a SQL database when we use nested JoinColumn in entity

Tags: java, sql, spring, many-to-one

I am going through some code and it uses nested `@JoinColumn` for one of the associations, as following:

```java
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "QuestId"), @JoinColumn(name = "GuildId")})
private GuildQuests guildQuest;
```

I understand that when I do something like the following:

```java
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns(name="GuildQuestId")
private GuildQuests guildQuest;
```

I am creating a column with the name `GuildQuestId` in the table and it has a foreign key constraint with the entity `GuildQuests`.

However, what will the nested `@JoinColumn`(first code snippet) do?

Answer (score 1):

Your first snippet is saying that you specify multiple foreign keys for the same association.

Example:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="ADDR_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"),
    @JoinColumn(name="ADDR_ZIP", referencedColumnName="ZIP")
})
public Address getAddress() { return address; }
```

Edit:
You're actually not creating any foreign keys with (both example) in the database. If you use for example Hibernate, Hibernate does not create any foreign keys on database level itself.